# Java condition AND or OR

Tags: java, conditional-statements

How are these two conditions any different from each other, one is using || with parentheses and other is with &&.

```
if (!(A.equals(param) ||  B.equals(param))) 
            System.out.println("True");


if (!A.equals(param) && !B.equals(param)) 
            System.out.println("True");
```

Thanks

Comment: Read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: What makes you think they are different?

Comment: Well I am in doubt so need some confirmation,

Comment: They are equivalent.  In any boolean equation you can surround in !(....) swapping the AND/OR and it will be the same.

Comment: Also for and negativ statement like this which would be preferred for readability?

Answer (score 2):

`(!A) && (!B)` needs both to be false to be true

`!(A || B)` needs both to be false to be true

So the 2 peices of code produce the same output for all inputs

These rules about `and` and `or` are known as [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

[image]

Graphicly, the area that is not in A or B (not covered by either circle) is the same as the area that is not in A and B circles combined

`(!A) && (!B)`= The area that is not in the red or the blue circle

`!(A || B)` = The area that is not in the red and blue circles combined

Answer (score 1):

&& returns true if both of the values are true,
|| returns true if one of the values are true,
But in your situation, both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From [De Morgan's laws:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> (!A && !B) is equivalent to !(A || B)

and

> (!A || !B) is equivalent to !(A && B)